# WPF: binding to a listbox based on another listbox selected item

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, listbox

I have a list of objects (let's call them Category) which holds a list of Items. So:

```
ObservableCollection<Category> Categories = new ObservableCollection<Category>();

public class Category
{
    ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
    public Category()
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
    }
}
```

Now. I have one listbox which is bound to the Categories and I have another that is bound to the Items of the SelectedItem in the first listbox. So:

```
<ListBox x:Name="FirstListBox" ItemsSource={Binding Categories} />

<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.Items, ElementName=FirstListBox}" />
```

Now, this works nicely. However, I am getting new data for the listboxes at set intervals. The problem I have is that when the new data comes in and I set it to the Categories, the SelectedItem of FirstListBox changes, and so I lose the populated items in the second ListBox. I presume because I am clearing the categories and adding them back in every time I poll that data.

```
currentData.Categories.Clear();
foreach (Category category in newData.Categories)
{
    currentData.Categories.Add(category);
}
```

Does anyone know of a way around this?

Comment: how about don't clear it? I know it sounds like being rude, but you identified the problem yourself. So why don't you try not clearing it and check your poll results and update the collection if already present or append/remove from it as needed.

Comment: Well, the problem with that is I would need to dig down and check every property of each class (Item and Category) to see whether it has changed (unless there is an easier way of checking?). Not the end of the world but if there is a nicer solution then I'd like to know. Also, I have not tested it but I am guessing that any change to the collection will cause the listbox to update it's selecteditem  value?